# Allegro 5 does not respond to keyboard events or window closing after going out of focus

Tags: allegro5

The title says it all. Everything works properly (I can use the esc button or press X to exit the window) while the window is in focus, but as soon as I minimize it, or open another window, when I put the Allegro app in focus again- the Events don't work anymore. It doesn't react to Escape or X anymore. Any solutions?

Code:

```
#include <allegro/allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro/allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro/allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro/allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro/allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro/allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <iostream>

#define SCREENWIDTH 800
#define SCREENHEIGHT 600

using namespace std;

bool running = true;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    al_init();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();
    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display = al_create_display(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
    ALLEGRO_FONT* font = al_load_font("soviet.ttf", 36, 0);
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE* event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));


    if(!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, "Could not initialize Allegro 5", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_YES_NO);
        return -1;
    }

    if(!display)
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "ERROR", "Display settings", "Display window was not created sucessfully", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_YES_NO);
        return -1;
    }

    int x1 = 10;
    int y1 = 10;
    int x2 = 30;
    int y2 = 30;

    while(running)
    {
        ///OnUpdate
        ALLEGRO_EVENT events;
        al_peek_next_event(event_queue, &events);

        if(events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            if(events.keyboard.keycode == ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE)
            {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
        {
            running = false;
            break;
        }

        x1++;
        y1++;
        x2++;
        y2++;

        ///OnRender
        al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255), 200, 200, 0, "Test");
        al_draw_filled_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0));

        al_flip_display();
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
        al_rest(0.05);
    }

    ///DEALLOCATE MEMORY
    al_destroy_font(font);
    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`al_peek_next_event()` does not remove the event and it does not block. So your code will not work correctly for both of those reasons.

If you replace it with `al_wait_for_event()` (which blocks and remove the event), then I think your code will do what you expect it to do.

Comment: My code does work. It's the events that stop working after the app window goes out of focus and back.
If I set it up with al_wait_for_event() my game loop will only run while I press and hold the keys in the event catcher.
So, I really don't find your answer helpful, unless I didn't understand it 'cause of my noobness. xD

Comment: @MatejŠtajduhar. That is because you should add a timer to the event queue as well. Otherwise, you can also use `al_get_next_event()`, but only process the event if it returns `true`. `peek` is absolutely the wrong function to use here.